# How to get SavedRequest in Spring Security 3 in login.jsp?

Tags: spring-security

How to get SavedRequest in Spring Security 3 in login.jsp ? I found an example :

```
<%@page import="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.SavedRequest"%>
<%

SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest) session.getAttribute(AbstractProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY);

.... %>
```

But this doesn't work in SpringSecurity 3.

Answer (score 0):

you should use DefaultSavedRequest.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY as the key